# Spring Boot Test and Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-test

@WithMockUser not taking the mocked user while testing a method secured with @PreAuthorize(). I am getting org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials exception as it is taking 127.0.0.1 as user and hitting the database to check for authentication.

How can I fix this behavior? It should take mocked user and doesn't go for the authentication in ideal scenario.

Below is the method I want to test:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_GST','ROLE_SUPER_GST','ROLE_CARGO_ASSURANCE_SUPER_USER', 'ROLE_CARGO_ASSURANCE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/task/bulkupload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = {
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<ApInvoicesResponse<BulkOperation>> bulkUpload(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile documentToStore) {
        ApInvoicesResponse<BulkOperation> successfulResponse = new ApInvoicesResponse<>();
        try {
            BulkOperation bulkOperation = taskService.bulkUpload(documentToStore.getBytes());
            successfulResponse.setData(bulkOperation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("apinvoicesmessage:invalid document received : {} {}",e.getMessage(),e);
            
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(successfulResponse);
    }
```

This is the abstract class I created for set up:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class ControllerTest {

    
    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void applySecurity() {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        Authentication authentication =
                new TestingAuthenticationToken("username", "password", "ROLE_USER");
        context.setAuthentication(authentication);

        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
    }


}
```

Below is test method that I have written:

```
class ApInvoicesCmdControllerTest extends  ControllerTest{



    @MockBean
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles={"USER"})
    public void testBulkUpload_GSTUser_Successful() throws Exception {
        MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "test-file.txt", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, "test data".getBytes());
        BulkOperation bulkOperation = new BulkOperation();
        Mockito.when(taskService.bulkUpload(file.getBytes())).thenReturn(bulkOperation);
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/task/bulkupload").file(file))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data").value(bulkOperation));
        verify(taskService, times(1)).bulkUpload(file.getBytes());
    }

  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@WithMockUser(roles={"USER"})` but the controller method you are testing is using another roles :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_GST','ROLE_SUPER_GST','ROLE_CARGO_ASSURANCE_SUPER_USER', 'ROLE_CARGO_ASSURANCE_USER')")
```

They should match existing roles. Change your test method annotation with :

```
@WithMockUser(roles={"ROLE_GST","ROLE_SUPER_GST","ROLE_CARGO_ASSURANCE_SUPER_USER", "ROLE_CARGO_ASSURANCE_USER"})
```

If I were you, I will write a **unit** test per role to validate each single role to allow method usage.

```
@WithMockUser(role="ROLE_GST")
//... test for ROLE_GST

@WithMockUser(role="ROLE_SUPER_GST")
//... test for ROLE_SUPER_GST
@WithMockUser(role="ROLE_CARGO_ASSURANCE_SUPER_USER")
//... test for ROLE_CARGO_ASSURANCE_SUPER_USER

// etc.
```

EDIT: I have checked some things. Do you use an existing user with the existing role inside your system (db, in-memory, etc.) ?

I am using these with an existing user with role I want to test, and it works well.

Below an example to initialize the security context in tests, which is missing inside your testing code :

```
@Slf4j
@Tags({ @Tag("web"), @Tag("controllers"), @Tag("IT") })
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class AdminUtilisateursUpdatePasswordIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private  ApplicationAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Mock
    private  AuthUserService authUserService;

    @Mock
    private  IdentificationService identificationService;

    @Mock
    private AuthJpaUserDetailsService authJpaUserDetailsService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AdminUsers adminUsers;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .build();
    }


    @Test
    @Order(1)
    @WithMockAuthUserGeneric
    void doGetPasswordFormNotAuthorizedWithRedirection() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Testing ADMIN > USER ACCOUNT > PASSWORD UPDATE > DISPLAY FORM with url : {} (FAILED, AccessDeniedException).",
                new Object[]{WebAppUrlsMapping.URL_MAPPING_ADMIN_USER_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD});

        mockMvc.perform(get(WebAppUrlsMapping.URL_MAPPING_ADMIN_USER_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andExpect(result -> {
                    assertTrue(result.getResolvedException() instanceof AccessDeniedException);
                })
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl(WebAppUrlsMapping.URL_MAPPING_ERROR_PROTECTED_ZONE))
                .andReturn();
    }

// ... other tests

}
```

Comment: Using the same roles as defined for the method, I am getting ` Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser(authorities={}, password="password", roles={"ROLE_GST", "ROLE_SUPER_GST", "ROLE_CARGO_ASSURANCE_SUPER_USER", "ROLE_CARGO_ASSURANCE_USER"}, setupBefore=TEST_METHOD, username="", value="user")`  exception. It seems like there is some issue with security context while running the test cases.

Comment: I think it's because you can use one role at a time here.

Comment: I have checked some things. Do you use an existing user with the existing role inside your system (db, in-memory, etc.) ? I am using these with an existing user with role I want to test, and it works well.

Comment: I am getting the same exception even after using one role at a time.

Comment: In my case I am using existing user with pre-defined roles in dev. But I want to mock the user authentication instead of using the database. For this reason, I used @WithMockUser() in the hope that I will get an already authenticated user.

Comment: And you didn't get it, strange thing. Looking again your code.

Comment: I am using only `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` and custom annotations with mocked users to in other envs than dev. I will post an example in another edit.

Comment: Edited post. Check the security context initialization. I think it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Still getting the same issue. Only thing that I found different is the security implementation is done in another application which we are using as a dependency. Also, we are using http.oauth2ResourceServer() for configuration.

Comment: Okay, maybe a custom config then to initialize before testing while using the spring resource server. Does it's own configuration well loaded while you are running your test suite? I think that's the point to check in.